# Qt installEventFilter() for all children of a Tab Page

Tags: c++, qt, mousehover, eventfilter

I am trying to capture hover events for all children of a TabWidget page. I subclassed QObject and reimplemented the eventFilter() to emit a signal to populate a label. The signal sends the name of the target object and a chosen language (e.g."English") as arguments. The label has a slot that takes this information and chooses an appropriate text file to read and display information. It is similar to displaying a tool tip but I need it to be diaplyed within the label.
Header:

```
#include <QEvent>
#include <QObject>

class ToolTipGenerator : public QObject
{
    public:
        ToolTipGenerator();
        void setLanguage(QString lang);

    protected:
        virtual bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);

    private:
        QString language;

    signals:
        displayToolTip(const QString &lang, const QString &targetName);
        clearToolTip();
};
```

Source:

```
#include "ToolTipGenerator.h"

ToolTipGenerator::ToolTipGenerator()
{
    language = "English";
}

void ToolTipGenerator::setLanguage(QString lang)
{
    language = lang;
}

bool ToolTipGenerator::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::HoverEnter)
        emit displayToolTip(language, obj->objectName());
    else if(event->type() == QEvent::HoverLeave)
        emit clearToolTip();

    return false;
}
```

MainWindow.cpp:

```
connect(generator, SIGNAL(displayToolTip(QString,QString)),
            ui->toolTipLabel, SLOT(displayToolTipInLabel(QString,QString)));

void MainWindow::displayToolTipInLabel(const QString &lang,
                                       const QString &targetName)
{
    QFile file(toolTipPath + targetName + "_" + lang + ".txt");
    QString line;

    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        while (!stream.atEnd())
            line.append(stream.readLine()+"\n");

        if(ui->tabWidgetSensor->currentIndex() == 1)
            ui->toolTipLabelPage1->setText(line);
    }
    file.close();
}
```

I now have to install the event filter for every child of a tab page.
Is there a better way to do this entire thing? Or at least a better way to install event filter for all the children without looping over all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could install the event filter on the `QApplication` object so it will see all events.

Then, in the `eventFilter` you check if the object in question has your tab widget base as a parent (or generally as an ancestor if you also want to have children's children).

Something like

```
bool ToolTipGenerator::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::HoverEnter) {

        // compare with your target parent or loop if any ancestor should be checked
        if (obj->parent() == youPage)
            emit displayToolTip(language, obj->objectName());
    }
    // ....
}
```